# How to traverse through a tree like nested data structure of unknown depth in order to find and collect addressable array items?

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures, tree, find

Say I have an array that looks as such:

```
[{
  "name": "Audiograms",
  "folders": [{
    "name": "2022"
  }, {
    "name": "2021"
  }, {
    "name": "2020"
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Patient Paperwork"
}, {
  "name": "Repairs"
}]
```

And this array can have an infinite amount of objects and sub-objects, similar to a file tree.

I have an array letting me know the name of the folders I need to access from the root of the object, like:

```
["Audiograms", "2022"]
```

I also do not know this value ahead of time, nor do I know how many items are in this array ahead of time.

How would I be able to actually traverse this file tree using the array of names? I wish to do things like maybe pop the matching object out and move it to another part of the file tree.

Thank you!

Comment: You are asking very broad questions about recursion here. Try starting by creating a function with a `for` loop that iterates through each of the objects in the array. Then you can check if `element.folders` is an array and is not empty, if so, then use the same function but with `element.folders` as the new array to iterate through. If you don't know the name of the keys, you can use `Object.keys(obj)` to get the keys from an object.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a depth-First (or Breadth-first) search algorithm... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search it is easiest to implement than it appear.

Comment: It would probably help if your input was and object with a `folders` property containing that array.  It would likely lead to much simpler code.

Comment: Let's say, the process passes `["Audiograms", "2022"]` as _**destination address**_, which return value does the OP actually expect? Also, what happens in case an address i not unique?

Comment: Suppose your data array is `dataArray` and your keys (ie, `Audiograms` and `2022`) are in `keysArray`, then, please try: `const targetObj = dataArray.find(obj => ( 'name' in obj && obj.name && obj.name === keysArray[0] && 'folders' in obj && obj.folders && Array.isArray(obj.folders) && obj.folders.some(folder => ('name' in folder && folder.name && folder.name === keysArray[1]))));` and share your feedback. This will get you access to the actual object. If you need to `"pop"`, please use `.findIndex()` instead of `.find()`. It will get you the index.

Comment: @MathewCrogan ... From all the so far provided answers / approaches are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

OP

> *"I wish to do things like maybe pop the matching object out and move it to another part of the file tree."*

In order to achieve follow-up tasks like the above mentioned one, the next provided solution *walks* the OP's folder structure and collects for each addressable match an object of two references, `target` and `parent`, where the former is the reference of the to be found folder-item, and the latter is the reference of its parent folder-item.

The solution got achieved by a recursively implemented [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)r function.

```js
function collectAddressableFolderRecursively(collector, folderItem) {
  const { name = null, folders = [] } = folderItem;
  const {
    address: [parentName, childName], result,
  } = collector;

  if (name === parentName && folders.length) {
    const targetFolder = folders
      .find(({ name }) => name === childName) ?? null;

    if (targetFolder !== null) {
      result.push({
        target: targetFolder,
        parent: folderItem,
      });
    }
  }
  result.push(
    ...folders.reduce(collectAddressableFolderRecursively, {
      address: [parentName, childName],
      result: [],
    })
    .result
  );
  return collector;
}

const folders = [{
  name: 'Audiograms',
  folders: [{
  
    name: '2022',
    folders: [{

      name: 'Audiograms',
      folders: [{
        name: '2022',
      }, {
        name: 'foo',
      }],
    }],
  }, {
    name: '2021',
  }, {
    name: '2020',
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Patient Paperwork',
}, {
  name: 'Repairs',
  folders: [{

    name: 'Audiograms',
    folders: [{
      name: '2022',
    }, {
      name: 'bar',
    }],
  }, {
    name: 'baz',
  }],
}]
const address = ['Audiograms', '2022'];

const { result } = folders
  .reduce(collectAddressableFolderRecursively, {
    address,
    result: [],
  });
console.log({ address, result });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```